# Sockets programming use c

Tags: c, function, sockets

Socket programming is being implemented using c language.

I want to proceed until accept and send and recv processes in different functions.

For example
We would like to implement socket programming data transfer by calling a function called send_data() from a function called socket_strat().

Can you forward the data from the server socket created in socket_start() as a function of send_data as a variable?

```
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , read_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char client_message[2000];
    
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    //accept connection from an incoming client
    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connection accepted");
```

This is the server socket creation process to be used in start_socket, and proceed with accept() to wait for the client's access.

I want to call the send_data() function when the client is connected.

**send_data()function not yet implemented (The function below.)

```
write(client_sock , msg , strlen(msg));
```

The reason I'm implementing it like this is because...

This is because socket communication is required when a specific event occurs in a program that goes around the infinite loop.

Therefore, if you insert the start_socket() function into the program that goes around the infinite loop,

Communication is not possible normally because the socket is created and becomes infinite.

Comment: I did not read the code so I may have gotten it wrong: "_send and recv processes in different functions_" - sounds good enough. It also sounds like you aim for a single threaded program, right? If so, look into the `select` family of functions. (`poll`, `epoll`, ..., pure `select`).

Comment: To be precise, the accept process proceeds and the send() function proceeds from another function. Recv() is conducted on the Android app under development. [Single communication] 

I'll look for your answers!

Comment: Since you mention Android: Doing anything there without tapping into the existing framework is going to be painful (my personal experience). Use the existing framework instead.